# onLocationChanged is not calling

Tags: java, android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

hey this is my code for retrieving users location periodically

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

private void prepareLocationServices() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else {
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }
    }
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        if (!googleApiClient.isConnected() || !googleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lng = location.getLongitude();
    Log.d("location", location.toString());
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                prepareLocationServices();
            }
        }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    prepareLocationServices();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}
```

but `onLocationChanged` is not calling at all while I have Cellular Data and GPS enabled. What is wrong?

Comment: Does your code go past the if statement with "GoogleApiAvailability"?

Comment: yeah `onConnected` is calling @PabloBaxter

Comment: Where is the stop logic for the location updates?

Comment: I don't want to stop it. It should periodically update and get users location @PabloBaxter

Comment: I would strongly recommend against that, unless you know for a fact that your users are connected to a power source. Running location updates will deplete the battery very quickly. In regards to the stop logic, I was asking because if there is stop logic, it may be getting called.

Comment: No there isn't but after fixin this problem I will handle that thanks @PabloBaxtar